# Split the list in one column into different columns based on category VBA

Tags: excel, vba, list, split

I have a list of data In columns in a range A2:C50, that contains 3 unique category names in column A.
I would like to take that list and split it into 3 different groups in column D, G and J.

[image]

Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: Please share your own attempt (Excel formula or VBA) no matter if it doesn't work and explain what's wrong with it. Also, share if you're using Office 365, since there are some new Excel functions with which you can do that easily by using Excel formulas. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72699559/edit) at any time.

Comment: Have you tried using the advanced filter?

Comment: If it's only three groups and will stay at three groups you could use a formula:  `=FILTER($A$2:$C$50,$A$2:$A$50="CARR")`

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel is not Office 365 and you don't want to use advanced filter, then the sub is something like this :

```
Sub test()
Dim arr: Dim rg As Range: Dim i As Long: Dim v As Range

arr = Array("CARR", "DEF", "CM")
Set rg = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    With rg
        .Replace arr(i), True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set v = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
        .Replace True, arr(i), xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Union(v, v.Offset(0, 1), v.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Destination:=Cells(2, i * 3 + 4)
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

The sub make an array for your 3 unique category names into arr variable.
Set the range of the data in column A into rg variable.
Then it loop to each element in arr, find all cells which has the looped element name and set it as v variable.
Union the v, v offset(0,1) and v offset(0,2), copy the union range and paste into the expected destination cell.